# GraphQL HTTP: "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.register."

Tags: javascript, graphql, express-graphql

I am trying to mutate in GraphQL to create a new user but I get the error of

> Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.register.

[Screenshot of operation, variable and response here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK9tE.png)

**graphql/schema/schema.js**

```
const{ buildSchema } = require('graphql');

const schema =  buildSchema(`

type User { 
  _id: ID!
  email: String!
  username: String!
  token: String!
  createdAt: String!
}
input RegisterInput{
  username: String!
  password: String!
  confirmPassword: String!
  email: String!
}
type Query { 
  user(id: ID!): User
}
type Mutation { 
  register(registerInput: RegisterInput): User!
}
schema { 
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}
`)

module.exports = schema;
```

**graphql/resolvers/user.js**

```
const User = require('../../models/user.js');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const SECRET_KEY = 'oPXA96op!u%,`:}eT^.!|hvXohA~fa';

module.exports = {
    Mutation: {
        async register(
            _,
            {
                registerInput: { username, email, password, confirmPassword}
            },
            context,
            info
        ) {
            password = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

            const newUser = new User({
                email,
                username,
                password,
                createdAt: new Date().toISOString
            });

            const res = await newUser.save();

            const token = jwt.sign({
                id: res.id,
                email: res.email,
                username: res.username
            }, SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: '1h'});

            return{
                ...res._doc,
                id: res._id,
                token
            };
        }
    }
};
```

**graphql/resolvers/index.js**

```
const postResolver = require('./post');
const userResolver = require('./user');

const resolvers = {
    Mutation: {
        ...userResolver.Mutation
    },
    ...postResolver
}

module.exports = resolvers;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express'); 
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');

const MONGODB = ''; 

const schema = require('./graphql/schema');
const resolvers = require('./graphql/resolvers');
const PORT = 4000; 
   
const server = new ApolloServer({ schema, resolvers });

mongoose.connect(MONGODB); 
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() { 
  console.log('Connected to the Database.');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log('Mongoose Connection Error : ' + error);
});

const app = express(); 
app.use(cors());

let apolloServer = null;
async function startServer() {
    apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
        schema,
        resolvers,
    });
    await apolloServer.start();
    apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });
}
startServer();

app.use("/graphql", graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schema,
  rootValue: resolvers, 
  graphiql: true
}));

app.listen(PORT, function() { 
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

I have checked many previous posts about this mutation error but none have seen to be resolved, and also have done many modifications to the schema/resolver but has not worked. I have also posted on the GraphQL Discord for help, but have had no luck. I tried changing the server.js but it affected my queries from running so I reverted.

**/graphql/resolvers/post.js**

```
const Post = require('../../models/post.js');
const { GraphQLDateTime } = require ('graphql-iso-date');

const customScalarResolver = {
    Date: GraphQLDateTime
  };
  
  function posts() { 
    return Post.find({});
  }
  
  function post(args) {
    return Post.findById(args.id)
  }
  
  function createPost(args) {
    let post = new Post(args.postInput);
    return post.save();
  }
  
  function deletePost(args) {
    return Post.findByIdAndRemove(args.id);
  }
  
  function updatePost(args) {
    return Post.findByIdAndUpdate(args.id, args.postInput, { new: true }); 
  }
  
  module.exports = { posts, post, createPost, deletePost, updatePost, customScalarResolver}
```

Comment: Is your resolver function getting called?

Comment: `const server = new ApolloServer({ schema, resolvers });`, `apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ schema, resolvers, });` and `graphqlHTTP({ schema: schema, rootValue: resolvers, graphiql: true }));` are two servers too man I think, you should use only one of these. Also in the last one, you're passing `resolvers` as the `rootValue`, is that intended?

Comment: @Bergi yes, my post resolver function works perfectly.

Comment: As I can see for a reason your mutation returns `null` but you specified that you will return a non-nullable `User!` (! means nonnullabe). Let's check why is that.

Comment: @Aris when I make User nullable I get "register": null

Comment: @Bergi how would I modify for it to use the apolloServer then instead of graphQLHTTP

Comment: @Aris The `register` function the OP posted never returns `null` but always an object. Unless it throws an error - but there is no other error preceding that in the screenshot.

Comment: I am not a js developer sorry, but as I can understand then, the register mutation should return a User object only not null not anything else.

Comment: Can you please try to return a dummy user? Just for test purposes?

Comment: Another thing worth testing is to check if all the required fields are there. If something is missing then it wouldn't be possible to construct a User object, which means it wont return a User object.

Comment: @Aris return a dummy user in what way

Comment: on your muation's return have just a dummy user, nothing else.

         var obj = {  
....
          }
         return obj;

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qn3GBBt I tried just manually creating a new user on the database for now and when I try to query it I also get null...

Comment: That sounds like your schema doesn't actually contain resolvers, and falls back to returning `null` by default for everything. Are you sure that your `register` resolver function is getting called? How did you verify it?

Comment: Something seems odd here: `const resolvers = {
    Mutation: {
        ...userResolver.Mutation
    },
    ...postResolver
}`

Comment: The postResolver works fine though through it

Comment: What is `postResolver`? If it's an object containing a `Mutation` property, that overwrites the `Mutation: { ...userResolver.Mutation }` part and you likely end up with no `Mutation.register` resolver.

Comment: I edited to included post.js resolver

Comment: @Aris I was able to play around a bit and now get this https://imgur.com/G4JRRQV

Comment: Seems like it's a non-graphql issue. Maybe the username you try to access on your code is undefined and that's why it throws this error.